# iOS customized Framework's public interface not visible sometimes

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, carthage

I was following the tutorial on [Debugging Carthage Dependencies](http://allocinit.io/ios/debugging-carthage-dependencies/#the-symbolic-link-way). So I have create two framework [cat-names](https://github.com/jerryzhoujw/cat-names) and [dog-names](https://github.com/jerryzhoujw/dog-names), and include them in [iPuppyApp](https://github.com/jerryzhoujw/iPuppyApp)

At the end of after build, the error shows that `DogName` from `dog-names` is `unresolved identifier`,  and `CatName` from `cat-names` is OK.

I was wonder why, I think I create them just the same.

[image]

I found the difference(CatName fully generated, but I don't know why DogName not fully generated) as bellow:

DogName, go to definition:

```
  import SwiftOnoneSupport
```

CatName, go to definition

```
  import Foundation
  import SwiftOnoneSupport
  import UIKit
  import cat_names
  import cat_names.Swift

  //
  //  cat_names.h
  //  cat-names
  //

  //! Project version number for cat_names.
  public var cat_namesVersionNumber: Double
  public enum CatName : String {
      case Cat1
      case Cat2
      case Cat3
      case Cat4
  }

  public func allCatList() -> [cat_names.CatName]
```

BUT in both framework project, I didn't setup any difference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you included the class names in cat_names.h and dog_names.h ?

Comment: @alain.s  no, but they are global enum and global function, right?   And strange thing is CatNames is available but DogNames.